# Trying to get the value of message from any of the clicked form or button?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

The variable message in the script is returning undefined while the variable name is true... I want to actually the input text by from the name of the button clicked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".submitcc").click(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var message = $("#" + name).val();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the form that is calling the script above...

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="message" id="submitcc_2_2" />
    <button class="submitcc"name="submitcc_2_2">Send</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="message" id="submitcc_5_2" />
    <button class="submitcc"name="submitcc_5_2">Send</button>
</form>
```

is there something wrong?

Comment: Your code should work

Comment: Any error on browser console?

Comment: Where are you using your `message` variable?

Comment: your code is working fine, check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dm7k3ejc/)

Comment: It works, https://jsfiddle.net/hkbqffqa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of `message` is in the function only.

You have to use `$('input[name="message"]')` to get message from `input`.

You can use

```
var message = $('input[name="message"]').val();
```

Where you need the `message`

If you have multiple `form`s on the page:

```
$(function () {
    var message = '';

    $(document).on('click', ".submitcc", function () {
        message = $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).val();

        return false;
    });

    // You can use message here
});
```

Comment: The code above works but return null, if i have multiple forms on a page...any ideas how to get the input message from any button clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mike_manish/j2ojyLt3/)

Although you can directly access element using following way

```
var message = $('#submitcc_2_2').val();
```

Comment: What i'm trying to do is make the code work for multiple forms with different ID for the input message. ...any ideas?

Comment: Sorry i m not getting you. You code will work with multiple forms too. What is the issue?